# Function doesn't work on RaspberryPi but works on computer

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, raspberry-pi, typeerror

I'm trying to run Python3 code on my Raspberry Pi 3 and I'm getting weird error.

My line is :

```
contours, hier = cv2.findContours(fgmask, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Once I'm compiling it on my computer it works great, when I'm compiling it on my Raspberry Pi i'm getting the error :

> "valueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)"

When I'm deleting the " cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE"

I'm getting the error :

> "TypeError: Required argument 'method' (pos 3) not found"

Is there any other method to make it work on the Raspberry Pi?

Thank you

Comment: The error is about the return value, since you are writing `contours, hier =`, `python` expects the function `cv2.findContours` to return two values. Do you have the same `cv2` version on both systems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be, that you have varying OpenCV versions on your computer and your Raspberry Pi.

Any OpenCV version before 4.0.0 has the following [syntax](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga17ed9f5d79ae97bd4c7cf18403e1689a):

```py
image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(...)
```

All OpenCV versions starting from 4.0.0 have that [syntax](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0):

```py
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(...)
```

So, it seems you have some OpenCV 4.x.x on your computer, but for example some OpenCV 3.x.x or even 2.x.x on your Raspberry Pi. If so, you obviously should try to synchronize the used OpenCV versions on both devices.

**EDIT:** As FlyingTeller already points out in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58409806/function-doesnt-work-on-raspberrypi-but-works-on-computer/58409966#comment103163334_58409806), the actual error is, that `cv2.findContours(...)` for any OpenCV version before 4.0.0 generates a tuple of three values, which you try unpack into two variables, which isn't possible. So, it has nothing to do with the number of parameters you provide to `cv2.findContours(...)`.

Hope that helps!